# Live Video Streaming In website

Tags: asp.net, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, webcam-capture

My knowledge in programming is **limited**. I was recently asked to develop a webpage to stream live camera. The webpage should act as both client and server. I tried to do this with asp.net but couldnt invoke activex library in a web browser.

Can anyone please let me know, which is the starting point for my project and which is the best programming language to use?

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class Form1
{
    private void Button2_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TcpClientActivex1.isListening) {
            TcpClientActivex1.StopListening();
            sender.Text = "Host";
        } else {
            TcpClientActivex1.StartListening();
            sender.Text = "Stop Listening";
        }
    }
    private void Button3_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TcpClientActivex1.isConnected) {
            TcpClientActivex1.Disconnect();
        } else {
            string ip = Interaction.InputBox("Enter the host IP address");
            if (!(ip == null))
                TcpClientActivex1.Connect(ip);
        }
    }

    private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TcpClientActivex1.isListening == false && TcpClientActivex1.isCameraOn) {
            TcpClientActivex1.StopCamera();
            sender.Text = "Start Camera";
        } else {
            TcpClientActivex1.StartCamera();
            TcpClientActivex1.FrameRate = 21;
            sender.Text = "Stop Camera";
        }
    }

    private void TcpClientActivex1_Connected()
    {
        Button3.Text = "Disconnect";
        Label1.Text = "Connected!";
    }

    private void TcpClientActivex1_Disconnected()
    {
        Button3.Text = "Connect";
        Label1.Text = "Disonnected!";
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TcpClientActivex1.isListening)
            TcpClientActivex1.StopListening();
        if (TcpClientActivex1.isConnected)
            TcpClientActivex1.Disconnect();
    }

    private void TcpClientActivex1_LostConnection()
    {
        Label1.Text = "Connection Lost";
    }

    private void TcpClientActivex1_OnConnection()
    {
        Label1.Text = "Connection Received";
    }
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpClientActivex1.Width = Panel2.Left;
        TcpClientActivex1.Height = Panel2.Height;
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        Resize += Form1_Resize;
        FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need help developing an ActiveX control to serve and receive video? Or do you need help embedding a finished ActiveX control in the web page? Your code looks like WinForms, not ASP.NET.

Comment: I have this Activex from a web source. But his doesnt seem to work in a aspx web page. I need help designing a activex which can stream live video feed from web cam. The activex must send and receive video feed.

Comment: I want to create a plugin for the browser that can enable video streaming and

Comment: Basically, an ActiveX is a rich client application. It can be embedded in a browser, or other applications. Creating a plugin for video streaming is a huge task that goes beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: Why not use flash or webrtc?

Comment: Thanks for replying, can you elaborate using with flash? I search internet but I find it difficult get the article.